# Snapping multiple vertex/edges/faces

Tags: edit-mode, snapping

I try to learn Blender to use on home workstation instead of 3Ds Max.
Can't find solution for obvious in 3D max snapping task - select multiple vertex / edges / faces than point some vertex or midpoint etc. then click on it, drag and move selected elements. Then snap them all to something not by center or some  "closest" but by pointed before vertex or some other.

For example how it works in 3DMax

[image]

Is there a possibility to snap like this?
I searched a lot but find just tons of trivial tutors about obvious things like grid snapping etc.
This basic functionality, without which I can't imagine modeling and I can't find it in Blender.
Certainly here it can be done in different way but I do not know how. Maybe I need some Add-Ons to install?

Help please.

Comment: You can use Active mode of snapping which means that moved geometry will be snapped by that element which is active (last selected/deselected). To point which element to snap to hover mouse over it, maybe that could help you..

Comment: Nice try but it does not work this way - snap mode " active " then snap with last selected. Did you try this yourself before write an answer? 

![Valid XHTML](http://imgur.com/a/8d41Y).

Anyway snapping alignment is still to center of selected.

Maybe I just do something wrong? But I can't find anything similar on YouTube so I do not know how this should be done.

Maybe some one else have better ideas how can I do this.

Comment: Yes, you did something wrong, selection should be done with mouse. Element won't become active if it's selected with border select. I always try what I write and suggest you doing the same.

Comment: It works !!! :) When select by click but not by frame. Thank you.